# Flutter TextInputAction.next doesn't move to the next input field when pressing next on Android keyboard

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

Below there is a minimal code fragment from a password-change widget reproducing the issue.
I'm using flutter 3.3.10 on windows 10 and a real (not emulated) ZTE Blade A5 device with Android 9.

A form with `TextFormField` for password and password-confirmation.
TextFormField both have  `textInputAction: TextInputAction.next` and an `InputDecoration` with a show/hide button.

show/hide buttons have an onPressed() function to change field content visibility status.

On input action , pressing "next" on android keyboard button on the first TextFormField, the focus doesn't move to next field if espectedthe onPressed function is not null;

If I set onPressed: null in the first or both TextFormField, textInputAction "*next*" works as expected. I tried `focusNode` too without success.

Is there a way to get it working ?
Thanks!

```
void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  bool _obscurePassword = true;
  bool _obscureConfirmPassword = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                 TextFormField(
                  obscureText: _obscurePassword,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password),
                    suffixIcon: MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      minWidth: 0,
                      child: Icon(_obscurePassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => _obscurePassword = !_obscurePassword),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Password",
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: _obscureConfirmPassword,
                  controller: confirmPasswordController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password),
                    suffixIcon: MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      minWidth: 0,
                      child: Icon(_obscureConfirmPassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => _obscureConfirmPassword = !_obscureConfirmPassword),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Password confirmation",
                  ),
                ),
               ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with `textInputAction: TextInputAction.next` not working when using password/confirm password fields with obscure password input decorations.

I was able to get it working correctly by adding an `onEditingComplete` handler for the password's `TextFormField` that does a `requestFocus()` to the move to the confirm password's `FocusNode`.

I got the idea from @gspencergoog's comment on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63575

Modified code (see `//ADDED` comments)

```
void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  late final FocusNode confirmPasswordFocusNode;  //ADDED
  bool _obscurePassword = true;
  bool _obscureConfirmPassword = true;

  @override
  void initState() {    //ADDED
    super.initState();
    confirmPasswordFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {   //ADDED
    confirmPasswordFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                 TextFormField(
                  obscureText: _obscurePassword,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password),
                    suffixIcon: MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      minWidth: 0,
                      child: Icon(_obscurePassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => _obscurePassword = !_obscurePassword),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Password",
                  ),
                  onEditingComplete: () {    //ADDED
                    // Move the focus to the next node explicitly.
                    confirmPasswordFocusNode.requestFocus();
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: _obscureConfirmPassword,
                  controller: confirmPasswordController,
                  focusNode: confirmPasswordFocusNode,    //ADDED
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password),
                    suffixIcon: MaterialButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      minWidth: 0,
                      child: Icon(_obscureConfirmPassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() => _obscureConfirmPassword = !_obscureConfirmPassword),
                    ),
                    labelText: "Password confirmation",
                  ),
                ),
               ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     );
  }
}
```